# subsets in spring/hibernate entity mappings

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

In spring/hibernate, what is the best way to handle subsets of data that need to be used in different situations?

I have a spring mvc app using hibernate to create an interface for a massive database in MySQL with millions of rows per table.  Some of the JSP views in the app will only interact with a given subset of perhaps 100,000 of the rows in a given table that might have 10,000,000 rows in total. I want the view to retrieve data quickly, so I tried creating a new database table with the 100,000 rows, matched by a new entity to map to the new database table.  But this will likely lead to complicated code.  What is a better way to get the speed improvements of only working with a subset of the data?

Here is what I have so far:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "conc_dual_key")
public class ConcDualKey {

    @Id
    @Column(name="dualkey")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})//
    @JoinTable(name="conc_dual_key_junction_new",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="dualkey")},
        inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name = "conceptid", referencedColumnName="id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name="effectiveTime", referencedColumnName="effectiveTime", insertable = false, updatable = false)})
    private Set<Concept> concepts = new HashSet<Concept>();

    //getters and setters
}
```

I then just made a copy of this entity with different table mappings in the database, to new tables that I created to contain the subset data:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "conc_finding_dual_key")
public class ConcFindingDualKey {

    @Id
    @Column(name="dualkey")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})//
    @JoinTable(name="conc_finding_dual_key_junction_new",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="dualkey")},
        inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name = "conceptid", referencedColumnName="id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name="effectiveTime", referencedColumnName="effectiveTime", insertable = false, updatable = false)})
    private Set<Concept> concepts = new HashSet<Concept>();

    //getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't duplicate reuse the same entity combine annotations with some xml mapping to specify the table. To retrieve use the name you gave the entity instead of the class.

```
<entity-mappings
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd"
                 version="2.0">

    <entity name="ConcDualKey" class="ConcDualKey" table="conc_dual_key" />
    <entity name="ConcFindingDualKey " class="ConcDualKey" table="conc_finding_dual_key" />

</entity-mappings>
```

Something like this. You could also make the `ConcFindingDualKey` read-only.

The mappings go in a file called `orm.xml` this file should reside in the `META-INF` directory of your project. (That is the default location specified in the JPA specification, you can put it anywhere but then you have to explicitly tell hibernate where to find the file by including a `mapping-file` element in the `persistence.xml`).

Comment: +1 and Thank you for thinking about this, but I do not understand what you mean yet.  Where do you suggest that I place the `<entity-mappings>` code?  I did a search in my eclipse workspace, and the only files with that string were located inside `hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar`.  Also, how would my entity code change to reflect the xml mapping that you suggest?

Comment: In JPA you can provide a `orm.xml` file to provide the (additional) mappings. You can put it next to your persistence.xml (i.e. in `META-INF`).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of duplicating the table, create an [updatable view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-updatability.html).

Comment: Thank you for giving a new idea.  But my question is about hibernate/spring mappings and modeling.  How would my spring and hibernate code change if I used your updatable view approach?

Comment: You would use the view the same way as you were using your subset table. Except that it wouldn't really be a different table.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I use the following syntax above the entity in the code from my original posting above: `@Table(name = "name_of_updatable_view")`?  If not, what exactly would you change?

Comment: Yes. You would use the view as if it were a table.